# Add items to the lists having lookup relation using powershell?

Tags: list, powershell, lookup-column

I am trying to add items to the comments list based on the Post list having lookup relation ship between these two lists,can any one give me an example how to update the lookup column values using powershell in sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

You can either use PowerShell formatting to provide a string representation, or create a new SPFieldLookupValue object:

```
$lookupValueString = "{0};#{1}" -f $post.ID,$post.Title
$lookupValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue -ArgumentsList $post.ID,$post.Title
```

Then you assign the value to a field and then Update the item.

```
$comment["PostTitle"] = $lookupValue
$comment.Update()
```